# Passing HTML content in $scope object in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular.js and I am playing with it, I am getting an issue when passing the HTML content with $scope object. 
It returns as a string on browser.

Here what I am doing with my controller

```
function htmlCtrl($scope, $http,Project) {
  $http.get('/content').success(function(data){
    //  data contains HTML value 
    $scope.projects=data;
  });
}
```

And in HTML file I am doing this

```
body     
  div
    div ng-view
    /div
  /div
      !-- /container --
/body
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The $sce is what you are looking for, but if you are going to put html snippets, why not use ng-include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service.

Like this

```
$scope.project = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
```

As for v1.0.3 use [ngSanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize), example of using is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0ajg8m6s)

Comment: @abarik, include $sce in service dependency - function htmlCtrl($scope, $http,$sce, Project)

Comment: @abarik what version of angular do you use?

Comment: I am using this [version](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js)

Comment: @abarik, $sce is available from v1.2. For v1.0.3 which you use try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize, example of using is here http://jsfiddle.net/0ajg8m6s/